# How to align horizontally a group of buttons

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3

The result of this

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default pull-left" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search</button>

        <div class="divider"></div>

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Reset filters", "Index",
    null,
    new { @class = "btn btn-success custom pull-left", @style = "color:white", @role = "button" }
    )
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-default custom pull-right" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i> Export to Excel</button>

    </div>
```

Is this

[image]

What am I missing?
I want the two first buttons on the left and the export one on the right (horizontally aligned).

```
.divider{
    width:20px;
    height:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
.custom {
    width: 160px !important;
}
```

**Edit:** I meant horizontally

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the bootstrap stylesheet that's supposed to handle it, see that it gets loaded.
Or use something like this as style and test that it works: `.pull-right {float:right}`

Comment: I meant horizontally. Yet, the same result in the image. I apologize for my mistake.